# Why is the graphic layout erroring on "android:"

Tags: android, eclipse

I just started my first android app following Big Nerd Ranch Android Programming book and in doing the first exercise it has me enter the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text"
  />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/true_button"
    />

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/false_button"
    />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I switch back over to the graphical view it gives me a bunch of errors like:

```
"<LinearLayout>" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
   (1) Set to "wrap_content"
   (2) Set to "match_parent"
```

When I click to set it to one or the other it changes my XML to be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android1:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android1:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Why is it insisting I use `android1:` and not accepting `android:` for any values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in you xml namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

should be

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
  xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand the problem now.